# use history.js to detect if HTML4 is supported so I can bypass ajax

Tags: javascript, browser, history.js, html4

history.js is working flawlessly on my website, in browsers that support HTML5.  When a URL is clicked, it does an ajax call, and on complete, saves the state to the history.  I fade in the new content with the function update_content().

on HTML4 browsers, I just want the website to treat the URL as a normal URL and skip the AJAX.   I was hoping history.js has a method or function I can call to detect browser.  Pseudo code below.

```
$(document).on('click', 'a[data-type="content"]', function(event) {

    // pseudo code
    if(History.html4() ) { return; }

    event.preventDefault();

    var href = $(this).attr('href');

    $.get(href, function(data) { 

        var new_data = $(data).siblings('#main_wrapper').html();

        // update page with the new data!
        update_content(new_data);

        // add an item to the history log
        History.pushState({ html: new_data }, event.target.textContent, event.target.href);

    });

});
```

I have included ONLY the html5 history.js, so it doesn't attempt to put the # in the URL.

**Is there a method or function in history.js that I can use to detect if the current browser is an HTML4 browser, so I know to treat the link as normal?  Is there a better way to do this?**

I don't want to install a plugin like modernizr unless I have to.

Comment: What? Your actual question isn't exactly clear.

Comment: @sphanley whoops. cleared up!

Comment: What do you mean by "know to redirect"? When are you redirecting, and to where?

Comment: @sphanley I added pseudo code to help represent.  If it's an HTML4 browser, treat the link as a normal link.  If it's an HTML5 browser, update the pushstate and fade in the content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't test if the browser supports HTML 4: That's a massively broad category.

Don't test if the browser supports form submission: They all do.

Test if the browser **doesn't** support the history API.

```
if (!history.pushState) {
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check, if `window.history` has a `pushState` method

```
if(!('pushState' in window.history)) {
    // doNothing();
    return;
}
```